# Excel VBA - read cell data from another workbook from function

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to read data from another workbook in a user defined function (Not macro) in excel VBA??

Comment: A UDF is a macro of sorts. What are you trying to do? Can you expand more please, and see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have many workbooks with costs information (one WB for each year), like: maintenance costs (meta data about the maintenance), I want to make a report workbook that uses a from/to date and update the report. Two years ago I tryed something like this and failed. Is it possible to do it with UDF? Or just by macros??

Comment: So basically, you want to access a closed workbook, and work with that closed workbook's data?

Comment: Thats the idea.. I will iterate thru the workbooks and fetch the required data. Im on the verge of converting the data to a database, but workbooks are more accessible for my coworkers.

Comment: What have you tried? You should be able to loop through a directory, using each Excel file in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, try to reference that `Workbook` like this

```
Function Plus5(Wkb as Workbook, sSheet as String, sRef as String) as Double
'' I'm guessing that is number the data you want
'' Wkb = Workbooks object, sSheet = Sheet Name; sRef = Cell Reference

Dim Wks as Worksheet
Set Wks = Wkb.Worksheets(sSheet)

Plus5 = Wks.Range(sRef) + 5

End Function
```